# Any way to create contacts in address book with bridging custom service in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

When we install whatsapp in android, then the contacts in address book are automatically synced with whatsapp contacts and the logo of whatsapp shows in front of them. So when we open that contact and click on whatsapp contact directly from there and we are sent back to whatsapp.

The same functionality I need in iPhone with my app. See thye attached screenshot.

[image]

If we click on that bubble then we will be sent back to new message page. The same way I want my icon with that contact and it should open my app. How to do this?

I want to do it by code (my app) itself.

If you have any idea or know any documentation then please share.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately it's impossible to implement such behavior in iOS.